# What is the linear approximation to $\sin(-0.5)$?

Tags: calculus

What is the linear approximation to $\sin(-0.5)$?

If $f(x) = \sin(x)$, should we use $x = \pi/3$ to approximate the value or use $x=0$?

Comment: What do you mean by "linear approximation to $\sin(-0.5)$"? $\sin(-0.5)$ is a **number**. Linear approximations, are calculated for **functions**.

Comment: @Gabrella It suggest you check out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568537/what-is-linear-approximation?rq=1) Math.SE post regarding linear approximations.

Comment: I meant what is the approximate value of sin(-0.5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for linear approximation is $f(x)\approx f(a)+f'(a)(x-a).$ Using $f(x) = \sin x$ this becomes $\sin x\approx\sin a +\cos a\cdot(x-a).$

We can choose any center, any $a$ value we like. You suggest $0$ and $\pi/3$ as options. I would suggest we also consider $-\pi/6,$ since that is a special angle that is close to $-0.5.$ Let's see:

$$
\sin(-0.5) \approx \sin(\pi/3) +\cos(\pi/3)\cdot (-0.5-\pi/3)\approx 0.0924266\\
\sin(-0.5) \approx \sin 0 +\cos 0\cdot (-0.5-0)=-0.5\\
\sin(-0.5) \approx \sin(-\pi/6) +\cos(-\pi/6)\cdot (-0.5-(-\pi/6))=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\approx -0.479563
$$

And my calculator tells me $\sin(-0.5)\approx -0.479426$. So our linearization at $a=\pi/3$ does not approximate the value of $\sin(-0.5)$ very well. The linearization at $a=0$ matches to one decimal place. And the linearization at $a=-\pi/6$ matches to four decimal places. So that one is the closest. To get the best approximation, you should choose the center for your linearization closest to your input value.

Comment: Why is sin x = sin a - cos a. (x-a)? Should it becomes sin x = sin a + cos a. (x-a)? Because the derivative of sin x is cos x

Comment: @Gabrella ok fixed. Thanks for the correction.